# Inverse Fourier transform and signal reconstruction

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm applying what's called a Wiener filter to a heart beat ECG signal. My problem is the Fourier and inverse Fourier transform which in theory should be easy. 
After getting Pxx and Pxxn. PSDs for a constructed desired signal and a the noise in our signal shifted so zero frequency in center. which I'm pretty sure I got right.

```
% frequency response function
for z= 1:Nfft
Hf(z)=Pxx(z)/(Pxx(z)+(Pxxn(z)));
end

% fourier transform on one ecg cycle 
ecgf=fftshift(abs(fft(ecg(100:800),Nfft)));

% getting the output signal
Yf=ecgf.*Hf;
figure;
plot(f,Yf,'green');
% inverse fourier transform 
Y=real(ifft(fftshift((Yf)),Nfft));
figure;
plot(Y);
```

What am I doing wrong? and can the output length of ifft be changed to what 700 to match the input signal or not.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Please be more specific.

Comment: Taking abs is going to destroy the phase component of your signal. Probably not what you want.